# Installation issue while installing ParlAI (Blenderbot2)

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, pip, blenderbot

need your help with an installation issue.

I am running a Ubuntu 20.4 machine and trying to install BlederBot2.
`https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAIe`

Using the following commands

```
pip install parlai
cd ~/ParlAI; python setup.py develop
```

It starts to try install but the I get the following message

```
ERROR: markdown 3.3.6 has requirement importlib-metadata>=4.4; python_version < "3.10", 
but you'll have importlib-metadata 4.2.0 which is incompatible.
```

I am very new to Python and would appreciate your help in understanding how this can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

i'm having the exact same issue. But, first, it appears parlAI doesn't support python 3.10, you have to look for a 3.9 or 3.8 version. Then, I'm force trying to get the right version of importlib-metadata by using:

```
pip install importlib-metadata==4.4
```

You can see which version best suits you, but! don't forget to downgrade your python first.

I just got the solution. Maybe this works for you too:

```
## First, in order to change your python version, use conda.
## If you don't know what it is, I highly recommend you to 
## search it. Well, the code:
conda create -n my_env python=3.8 ## Downgrade the python just for the project
conda activate my_env

cd ~/.conda/envs/my_env
git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI.git
cd ParlAI
pip install -r requirements.txt
python3 setup.py develop
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. I have followed the steps EXACTLY you mention but still cannot get it to work. Same message again. I suppose you did this on Ubuntu 20.04 right?

Comment: Also, at what point do you run the command pip install importlib-metadata==4.4

Comment: I was not using ubuntu 20.04 but fedora 34.
I now that I solved the problem, the reinstall of the importlib-metadata library wasn't neccesary, so just don't do it.

Do you have the same output from the beginning or is different?, still got the python_version < "3.10" problem ?